# Relacionamento 1 para 1 com EF Core e Identity

Tags: c#, .net, identity

Estou tentando fazer um relacionamento 1 para 1 entre 2 classes.

```
public class CustomUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public virtual CustomerInfo CustomerInfo { get; set; }
    public int CustomerInfoId { get; set; }
}
```

e

```
public class CustomerInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual CustomUser User { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string CPF { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
}
```

Eu tenho 2 contexts, o UserDbContext (para o Identity) e o AppDbContext para os outros modelos do projeto.

Fiz a configuração do relacionamento e coloquei no AppDbContext, mas deu erro na hora de gerar o UserDbContext dizendo assim:

> The dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one
> relationship between 'CustomUser.CustomerInfo' and
> 'CustomerInfo.User'. To identify the dependent side of the
> relationship, configure the foreign key property. If these navigations
> should not be part of the same relationship, configure them
> independently via separate method chains in 'OnModelCreating'. See
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=724062 for more details.

Então eu tive que colocar esse relacionamento TAMBÉM na UserDbContext. Se eu deixasse somente em 1 context, dava erro no outro, então teve que ficar nos 2. Ele gera a migration normalmente, PORÉM, o UserDbContext também gera uma tabela, então elas ficam duplicadas (a tabela de CustomerInfo), e também é gerada uma tabela para CustomUser, sendo que o correto é não gerar, uma vez que ela já é a tabela do proprio identity, a **AspNetUsers** .

Ficou desse jeito:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> opt) : base(opt)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        
        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
            .HasKey(a => a.Id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerInfo>()
            .HasKey(ci => ci.Id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerInfo>()
            .HasOne(ci => ci.Address)
            .WithOne(a => a.CustomerInfo)
            .HasForeignKey<Address>(a => a.CustomerInfoId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerInfo>()
            .HasOne(c => c.User)
            .WithOne(u => u.CustomerInfo)
            .HasForeignKey<CustomerInfo>(c => c.UserId);
    }            
    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CustomerInfo> CustomerInfos { get; set; }
}
```

e a outra:

```
public class UserDbContext : IdentityDbContext<CustomUser, IdentityRole<int>, int>
{
    public UserDbContext(DbContextOptions<UserDbContext> opt) : base(opt)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUser>()
        .HasOne(u => u.CustomerInfo)
        .WithOne(c => c.User)
        .HasForeignKey<CustomerInfo>(c => c.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
            .HasOne(ci => ci.CustomerInfo)
            .WithOne(a => a.Address)
            .HasForeignKey<CustomerInfo>(a => a.AddressId);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole<int>>().HasData(new IdentityRole<int>
        {
            Id = 99999,
            Name = "admin",
            NormalizedName = "ADMIN"
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole<int>>().HasData(new IdentityRole<int>
        {
            Id = 88888,
            Name = "user",
            NormalizedName = "USER"
        });
    }
}
```

Alguém sabe como fazer esse relacionamento entre tabelas de contextos diferentes?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o relacionamento em si você não consegue fazer.

Sugestão: deixe as entidades nas classes mas não mapeie o relacionamento. Crie um método para popular a entidade, que chamará o respectivo *dbContext*.

Alternativamente, deixe os dois *dbContexts* juntos.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Consegui resolver deixando tudo no UserDbContext. Antes dava erro porque eu tirei o relacionamento ali no modelBuilder mas deixei o DbSet<> mapeando a classe.